# Adding one week via java.util.Calendar.add() fails

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek

I'm trying to iterate in my Java program over all weeks between two dates (the end date being today). First, I get the starting date:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start = data.getFirstDate(users, threads);
```

So far, so good. The start date is correct and I can work with it. Now I iterate:

```
Calendar current = start;
while(current.before(Calendar.getInstance()) {
    // Do something
    current.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
}
```

Well, this kind of works. I start at 2002/8/23, then comes 2002/8/30, then 2002/9/7... **UNTIL** 2002/11/30. The date after that is 2003/0/6, which is neither correct nor even a valid date!

What am I doing wrong? I tried `current.add(Calendar.DATE, 7)`, `current.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1)`, `current.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7)` and two other ways. Using `current.roll(Calendar.DATE, 7)` does not work because I stay in the same month. Using `GregorianCalendar` has no effect as well.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Julian

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The month field in the `Calendar` API is 0-based not 1-based. So 0 stands for January. Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing 0 as a month, that's January since months are 0 index based. 0 is January and 11 is December.

Comment: @Joeri: Thanks. I misread the question, wrote a wrong answer and before I could edit it, I was downvoted. Gotta be more careful in the future ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think your interpretation of the dates is incorrect. The month field is zero-based, i.e. JANUARY is 0. So, 2002/11/30 is DECEMBER 30th.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().plusWeeks( 1 ).isBefore( stopDate )
```

## java.time

The modern answer uses *java.time* classes rather than `Calendar`.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
LocalDate weekLater = today.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
```

Get your starting date. You may specify the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December, unlike the crazy zero-based numbering in the legacy class.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Month is 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

From there, looping is just basic Java, using the `LocalDate` object’s comparison methods: `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual`.

```
LocalDate ld = start ;
while( ld.isBefore( today ) ) {
    ld = ld.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
    …
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).